# Error in Oracle Query while using XMLQuery with the below charecters in matches (.:–)%\-)

Tags: oracle

I have a below query in oracle with XMLQuery and matches function in that.

the below error is coming when i am trying to execute this query:

```
ORA-19114: XPST0003 - error during parsing the XQuery expression: 
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00806: Invalid token in the pattern
19114. 00000 -  "error during parsing the XQuery expression: %s"
*Cause:    An error occurred during the parsing of the XQuery expression.
*Action:   Check the detailed error message for the possible causes.
```

**can some one help in fixing this issue with matches function.**

Query:

```
select 
XMLQuery(
    '//node()[ancestor::emp_content or ancestor::stimulus_reference][not(ancestor::rationale)][self::text()][not(ancestor::inline_code) and not(ancestor::code_line)][**matches(.,"[0-9]+[^0-9,.:–)%\-  snrt]")** ]' 

    passing emp_cntnt_xml returning content
) as data
        
from emp where emp_num in (12345)
```

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<emp>
  <emp_content>
    <task>
      <emp_response>
        <response_choices>
          <choice_list>
            <choice numeric_identifier="1">10°</choice>
            <choice numeric_identifier="2">20°</choice>
            <choice numeric_identifier="3">36°</choice>
            <choice numeric_identifier="4">50°</choice>
            <choice numeric_identifier="5">72°</choice>
          </choice_list>
        </response_choices>
      </emp_response>
    </task>
  </emp_content>
</emp>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell this is an odd bug with the XQuery parser in Oracle.

It seems the `.` character in the regexp in the `matches` function is causing the problem.  This character appears in the negated character class `[^0-9,.:–)%-  snrt]`.  To confirm this, try taking it out of your regexp and seeing if the query works fine without it.

However, it's likely that the `.` is in your regexp because you wanted it to be there, so simply taking it out might not be an option for you.  After some experimentation I found that moving the `.` to the start of the negated character class gets around the problem, in that I no longer get an error about an invalid XQuery expression.

So, try replacing

```
matches(.,"[0-9]+[^0-9,.:–)%-  snrt]")
```

with

```
matches(.,"[0-9]+[^.0-9,:–)%-  snrt]")
```

I've tested that it works in Oracle LiveSQL: the script is [here](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/f83855x9i1kqnmu9elhcszhy1).

Comment: Thank you for your response, yes when i take out the character form regexp  it works, but i need the character in regexp. when i try  with matches(.,"[0-9]+[^.0-9,:–)%-  snrt]") it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: @Saritha: sorry to hear it's still not working for you.  I can only say that it works for me in Oracle LiveSQL: I've now edited my answer to add a link to the LiveSQL script I used.  If you are still getting the same error on your database even after moving the `.` character, you may have to raise a support request with Oracle.